# Why is the loading overlay randomly becoming null?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fragment with a loading overlay and a loading progress bar, from time to time it crashes throwing me this exception:

[image]

It's visibility is changing by overrided method:

```
class ObservableProgressBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ContentLoadingProgressBar(context, attrs) {

    var onVisibilityChangedListener: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun setVisibility(visibility: Int) {
        super.setVisibility(visibility)
        onVisibilityChangedListener?.invoke(visibility)
    }
}
```

It is a schrinked code of the fragment where the problem appears randomly:

```
class InitResetPasswordSessionFragment : BaseFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private lateinit var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_init_authentication_session,
            container,
            false
        )
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        appComponent.inject(this)

        authenticationViewModel = getViewModelFromActivity(viewModelFactory)

        authenticationAvailabilityLoadingProgressBar.onVisibilityChangedListener = {
            authenticationAvailabilityLoadingOverlay.visibility = it
        }

        authenticationViewModel.authenticationSessionState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            when (it) {
                is AuthenticationViewModel.AuthenticationSessionState.Idle -> {
                    findNavController().navigateUp()
                }
                is AuthenticationViewModel.AuthenticationSessionState.Initialized -> {
                    enableViews(true)
                    authenticationAvailabilityLoadingProgressBar.hide()
                }
                is AuthenticationViewModel.AuthenticationSessionState.Creating -> {
                    enableViews(false)
                    authenticationAvailabilityLoadingProgressBar.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it is appearing, I guess it might be because of fragment lifecycle, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was solved by removing custom listener of this loading overlay in `onDestroy()` method, because it was trying to get a reference for this and a related view before the fragment was in Resumed state.